# SeekToCurrentErrorHandler + ExponentialBackOff will log errors after backOff has passed, is that intentional?

Tags: spring-kafka

**Context:**

The docs in "stateful retry" (https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#stateful-retry) and "seek to current" (https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#seek-to-current) make it sound like that as a user, I should migrate away from a RetryTemplate to using the BackOff function in `SeekToCurrentErrorHandler`.

I currently have a mix of `RetryTemplate` with an infinite loop for certain exceptions + `SeekToCurrentErrorHandler` with a fixed retry of 3 times that works for all other exceptions.

Now I am looking to replace this attempt with `handler.setBackOffFunction((record, ex) -> { ... });`, but I have been facing following issue

But I am not sure if this intended, I am misconfiguring or if this is a bug.

- Spring Boot 2.4.0
- spring-kafka 2.6.3

**Question:**

When I am using the `SeekToCurrentErrorHandler` with large intervals, the error-message for "hey your listener threw an exception" appear to log AFTER a interval was done. Is this intentional? My code is throwing an exception and a log-entry may appear much after.

Here we line 1 executed at `22:59:14`. An exception is thrown shortly after, but appears in the logs 10s later at `22:59:24`. When using `ExponentialBackOff`, that timeframe becames larger and larger.

```
foo1 at 2020-11-20T22:59:14.850721600
2020-11-20 22:59:24.976  INFO 21456 --- [  kgh1235-0-C-1] o.a.k.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer     : [Consumer clientId=consumer-kgh1235-1, groupId=kgh1235] Seeking to offset 21 for partition kgh1235-0
2020-11-20 22:59:24.976 ERROR 21456 --- [  kgh1235-0-C-1] essageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer : Error handler threw an exception

org.springframework.kafka.KafkaException: Seek to current after exception; nested exception is org.springframework.kafka.listener.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener method 'public void de.roppelt.Application.listen(java.lang.String)' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Thrown at 2020-11-20T22:59:14.850721600; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Thrown at 2020-11-20T22:59:14.850721600
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.SeekUtils.seekOrRecover(SeekUtils.java:157) ~[spring-kafka-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
```

Reproduceable with following:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @KafkaListener(id = "so64937593", topics = "so64937593")
    public void listen(String in) {
        LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
        System.out.println(in + " at " + now);
        throw new RuntimeException("Thrown at " + now);
    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<?, ?> kafkaListenerContainerFactory(
            ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer,
            ConsumerFactory<Object, Object> kafkaConsumerFactory) {

        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Object, Object> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        configurer.configure(factory, kafkaConsumerFactory);
        SeekToCurrentErrorHandler eh = new SeekToCurrentErrorHandler((rec,ex) -> System.out.println("I am the dlq"), new ExponentialBackOff());
        factory.setErrorHandler(eh);
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public NewTopic topic() {
        return new NewTopic("so64937593", 1, (short) 1);
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(KafkaTemplate<String, String> template) {
        return args -> {
            IntStream.range(0, 10).forEach(i -> template.send("so64937593", "foo" + i));
        };
    }

}
```

I have found following to give me a logging right after:

```
RetryTemplate retryTemplate = new RetryTemplate();
retryTemplate.setListeners(new RetryListener[]{new RetryListener() {
    @Override
    public <T, E extends Throwable> boolean open(RetryContext context, RetryCallback<T, E> callback) {
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public <T, E extends Throwable> void close(RetryContext context, RetryCallback<T, E> callback, Throwable throwable) {
    }
    @Override
    public <T, E extends Throwable> void onError(RetryContext context, RetryCallback<T, E> callback, Throwable throwable) {
        System.out.println(LocalDateTime.now() + "Oops happened at " + context);
    }
}});
retryTemplate.setRetryPolicy(new NeverRetryPolicy());
factory.setRetryTemplate(retryTemplate);
```

So I am adding a retryTemplate with a "neverRetry" policy, so I can use the logger.
, where I now have an immediate feedback that an error happened.

```
foo1 at 2020-11-20T23:05:57.769425100
2020-11-20T23:05:57.769425100Oops happened at [RetryContext: count=1, lastException=org.springframework.kafka.listener.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener method 'public void de.roppelt.Application.listen(java.lang.String)' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Thrown at 2020-11-20T23:05:57.769425100, exhausted=false]
2020-11-20 23:06:07.897  INFO 22608 --- [  kgh1235-0-C-1] o.a.k.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer     : [Consumer clientId=consumer-kgh1235-1, groupId=kgh1235] Seeking to offset 21 for partition kgh1235-0
2020-11-20 23:06:07.897 ERROR 22608 --- [  kgh1235-0-C-1] essageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer : Error handler threw an exception
```

I think this is a bug, but I wanted to hold off and post here before submitting a github issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The log is written by the container **after** the error handler exits (we have no choice about that).

You can, however, suppress those logs by changing the log level on the `SeekToCurrentErrorHandler`. It sets the level on the exception and the container will log it at that level.

```java
/**
 * Set the level at which the exception thrown by this handler is logged.
 * @param logLevel the level (default ERROR).
 */
public void setLogLevel(KafkaException.Level logLevel) {
    Assert.notNull(logLevel, "'logLevel' cannot be null");
    this.logLevel = logLevel;
}
```

This has been available since 2.5.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#error-handlers

> Typically, the error handlers provided by the framework will throw an exception when the error is not "handled" (e.g. after performing a seek operation). By default, such exceptions are logged by the container at **ERROR** level. Starting with version 2.5, all the framework error handlers extend `KafkaExceptionLogLevelAware` which allows you to control the level at which these exceptions are logged.

If you want to log the root cause (original exception) before the back off, you can subclass the error handler and log before calling `super.handle(...)`.

If you want an option for the framework to log the error, before backing off, feel free to open a GitHub issue.

Comment: Thank you, that explains it. Works as designed, but I got several options.

Comment: I will submit an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Gary's ansere, I came up with following.

It loggs the exception right away with some context (attempt, topic, offset). Which is somewhat similar to what the LoggingListener in the retryTemplate offers.

```
public class LoggingSeekToCurrentErrorHandler extends SeekToCurrentErrorHandler {

    public LoggingSeekToCurrentErrorHandler(BiConsumer<ConsumerRecord<?, ?>, Exception> handler, BackOff backOff) {
        super(handler, backOff);
    }

    @Override
    public void handle(Exception thrownException, List<ConsumerRecord<?, ?>> records, Consumer<?, ?> consumer, MessageListenerContainer container) {
        ConsumerRecord<?, ?> record = records.get(0);
        TopicPartitionOffset recordPosition = new TopicPartitionOffset(record.topic(), record.partition(), record.offset());
        String delivery = container.getContainerProperties().isDeliveryAttemptHeader() ? ""+deliveryAttempt(recordPosition) : "NA";
        log.error("Listener threw an exception, attempt {}. On partition {} at offset {}. Record timestamp {}", delivery, recordPosition.getTopicPartition(), recordPosition.getOffset(), record.timestamp(), thrownException);

        super.handle(thrownException, records, consumer, container);
    }
}
```

Added to the factory:

```
factory.getContainerProperties().setDeliveryAttemptHeader(true); // optional, see https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#delivery-header
errorHandler.setLogLevel(KafkaException.Level.DEBUG); // since our handler already logs. Prevent double logging of stacktrace
```

Resulting sample:

```
@Slf4j
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @KafkaListener(id = "so64937593", topics = "so64937593")
    public void listen(String in) {
        log.info("Processing {}", in);
        throw new RuntimeException("Thrown at " + LocalDateTime.now());
    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<?, ?> kafkaListenerContainerFactory(
            ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer,
            ConsumerFactory<Object, Object> kafkaConsumerFactory) {

        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Object, Object> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        configurer.configure(factory, kafkaConsumerFactory);
        factory.getContainerProperties().setDeliveryAttemptHeader(true); // optional, see https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#delivery-header
        SeekToCurrentErrorHandler eh = new LoggingSeekToCurrentErrorHandler((rec,ex) -> log.error("I am the dlq"), new FixedBackOff(10_000, Long.MAX_VALUE));
        eh.setLogLevel(KafkaException.Level.DEBUG); // since our handler already logs. Prevent double logging of stacktrace
        factory.setErrorHandler(eh);
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public NewTopic topic() {
        return new NewTopic("so64937593", 1, (short) 1);
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(KafkaTemplate<String, String> template) {
        return args -> {
            IntStream.range(0, 10).forEach(i -> template.send("so64937593", "foo" + i));
        };
    }


    public static class LoggingSeekToCurrentErrorHandler extends SeekToCurrentErrorHandler {

        public LoggingSeekToCurrentErrorHandler(BiConsumer<ConsumerRecord<?, ?>, Exception> handler, BackOff backOff) {
            super(handler, backOff);
        }

        @Override
        public void handle(Exception thrownException, List<ConsumerRecord<?, ?>> records, Consumer<?, ?> consumer, MessageListenerContainer container) {
            ConsumerRecord<?, ?> record = records.get(0);
            TopicPartitionOffset recordPosition = new TopicPartitionOffset(record.topic(), record.partition(), record.offset());
            String delivery = container.getContainerProperties().isDeliveryAttemptHeader() ? ""+deliveryAttempt(recordPosition) : "NA";
            log.error("Listener threw an exception, attempt {}. On partition {} at offset {}. Record timestamp {}", delivery, recordPosition.getTopicPartition(), recordPosition.getOffset(), record.timestamp(), thrownException);

            super.handle(thrownException, records, consumer, container);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI, you can get the delivery attempt without enabling the header; just call `getDeliveryAttempt(recordPosition)`. Of course, this is moot if you want to expose the delivery attempt (via the header) to the application.

Comment: Oh good to know, I just assumed that it would not work or always be 1 if it was not enabled in the factory settings.

Comment: No; that flag simply tells the container to call that method to get the delivery attempt and add it as a header to the record.